# C++ templates and pre-process macro

Tags: c++, macros, non-type

Consider following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int I>
int myfunc()
{
#if I
    return 1; 
#else
    return 2;
#endif
};

int main()
{
    cout<<myfunc<0>()<<endl;
    cout<<myfunc<1>()<<endl;
}
```

But the output is

```
2
2
```

The motivation to do this is following:

I have an algorithm, which needs to be implemented in both double and fixed point. One solution is to use a head file to define data type based on macro flag, for example,

```
#ifdef __DOUBLE__
typedef double InputType;
.... // a lot of other types
typedef double OutputType;
#else  //Fixed Point
typedef int InputType;
... // a lot of other types, which are matching with "__DOUBLE__" section
typedef int OutputType;
```

The drawback of this type of solution is that you can't compare the two implementations at the runtime. You have to set the macro accordingly twice, compile twice, and run twice, and then compare the collected data. Ideally, I would like to have a template function or template class with a nontype parameter, which allows me to switch between implementations

Any other methodology can achieve the similar goal (comparing two implementation at run-time) is also welcome!

Thanks

Comment: you want to read about template-specialization

Comment: I think pre-process happens before compiling, while initiation of a template happens during compiling. That's why the code has undesired output.

Comment: You should not mix preprocessor pragma and template specialization... There is no way they are related.

Answer (score 3):

#### Option: Template Specialization

You can specialize templates to allow for separate implementations. Template specializations can de done for classes as well. Consider:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T) {
  //general implementation
}

template<>
void foo(double d) {
  //do something special for doubles
}

template<>
void foo(float f) {
  //do something else for floats
}
```

#### Option: Enum of types

This is similar to [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/). Something like this:

```
enum MyTypes {FLOAT, DOUBLE};

void foo(MyType _m) {
  //do some generic stuff
  switch(_m) {
    case FLOAT:
      //do something for float
      break;
    case DOUBLE:
      //do something else for float
      break;
    default:
      //runtime error
  }
  //do some other stuff
}
```

But it takes a parameter into the function instead of a template argument.

Comment: Yes. This is another solution. But it doubles the size of the implementations and behavior difference is easy to be overlooked.

Comment: You could use an enum for the types. This is the philosophy that OpenGL follows. Based on an enum do various things differently. But the syntax won't be like what you want.

Comment: Would you be more specific on this? Any reference or link? Thanks

Comment: added this second thought to my answer